# update total price after user clicks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a cart box , according to the user click.

My problem is, how to check if user updated a price. Tried setInterval but I dont quite get what I want ;) Should I use setInterval or try another way to update the total price? There are gonna be like 5 click functions.

```
$('#test_bt').click(function() {
    $('#test').append(500);   
});

$('#test2_bt').click(function() {
    $('#test2').append(20);    
});

setInterval(function(){
    $('#zamow_basket_box').each(function () {
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find('.item').each(function () {
            total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0
        });

        var $total = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'total',
            html: '<div>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</div>'
        });

        $total.appendTo('#zamow_total_price')
    })
}, 300);
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGuG4/)

Comment: You can make some variables to set when an element's value changes with `.on("change")` or you can place the initial value of each element to a property of those elements and compare em with the current values in click function. If they dont match that means the user has changed em.

Comment: You know if my logic fails, you could tell me how to make it works ;) I'm not talking its the best way, i'm here for solution and knowledge ...